# Can I use Microsoft Live SDK in windows 7?

Tags: c#, sdk, live, onedrive

In plain English I want my desktop c# windows 7 app to have "upload to onedrive" feature. I have been going in circles for hours and all code seem to point to ASP or windows store apps.

Is Live SDK restricted to windows 8 and can't be used for windows 7?
I came across code such as this which only work in visual studio 2012

```
LiveConnectClient client;
var auth = new LiveAuthClient("YourGeneratedKey");
var result = auth.InitializeAsync(new [] {"wl.basic", "wl.signin", "wl.skydrive_update" });

// If you're not connected yet, that means you'll have to log in.
if(result.Status != LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
{
    // This will automatically show the login screen
    result = await auth.LoginAsync(new [] {"wl.basic", "wl.signin", "wl.skydrive_update" });
}

if(result.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
{
     client = new LiveConnectClient(result.Session);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want full functionality you need windows 8. Why do you use onedrive? See other cloud storage solutions, I remember dropbox allows full access regardless of windows version.

Answer (score 3):

According to the system requirements of the Live SDK 5.5 it is possible to use Live SDK for Windows 7 and above. However many features are not available on Windows 7 and lower. So the answer is no, you cannot use Live SDK with the requirements you specify. This is because Live SDK uses the Managed API. There is an codeplex project named Pseudo Live SDK which allows you to use the Live SDK on Windows 7 and earlier. http://pseudolivesdk.codeplex.com/

Comment: pseudo Live SDK seem to do it. the problem is that it request login from the user each time. this application will be for my own use i don't want to be nagged by login. i want user name and password based log in (stored in application options).

Comment: What do you mean by 'each time'. Do use must log in once during the start up of your application. Anyway i don't believe its possible to sign in using the Live SDK without the SignInDialog.